# Verifying that dlm is working correctly

Tags: r, simulation, dlm

I am new to the dlm package and I am writing a simulation to verify that dlm is working correctly.

Here is how I proceed:

I create an AR1 series with parameters $\phi$ and $\sigma^2$.  Then I try to make a 95% Confidence interval for it's 2 parameters $\phi$ and $\sigma^2$. Then I verify that 95% of the times the created confidence intervals contain the original parameters(because that's how a confidence interval is defined).

Here is my formal algorithm:

```
1. Repeat many times(1000 times in my case)
2.     Generate $\phi$ and $\sigma^2$.
3.         Repeat 100 times:
4.         Simulate an AR1 series with parameters from 2.
5.         Compute 95% confidence intervals for $\phi$ and $\sigma^2$.
6.         Verify that 5% of the time the above CI does NOT contain 
           the parameters generated in step 2(this is equivalent to the                 
           CI containing the parameter 95% of the time).
7.         This amounts to saying that the distribution of number of          
           time the CI does NOT contain the original parameter is   
           Binomial(100,.05)
We will finally get 1000 element vector which SHOULD be  
distributed as rbinom(n=1000,size=100,p=.05)
I then do a qqplot of the observed vector with the expected vector.
```

The results are here :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The code is here: [Code](https://pastebin.com/MY2qHGVc)

My problem is that the qqplot is tilted in the plot for $\phi$. Can someone explain to me where I am wrong ?

Perhaps I was not clear.When I create a 95% CI then 95% of the times it will contain the original parameter and 5 % of the time it will not. I  generate $\phi$ and $\sigma^2$. Then I generate the CI for each parameter 100 times. I expect this to not contain the original parameter 5 times out of 100. That's my expected distribution.Repeated 1000 times this will be rbinomial(1000,100,.05). My observed distribution is the actual count of the number of times out of 100 the CI does NOT contain the parameter.Repeated 1000 times this will be a vector whose length is 1000 and mean =100* .05 = 5.
Then I do a qqplot and qqline for the expected and observed distributions.That's how I get the red line.

Comment: Dear Peter, I am asking the statistical query as to why my qqline is not 45 degrees. I am describing my algo and the output. Where should this query belong?

Comment: I think it belongs here but it will likely require a fair bit of work to be suitable

Comment: The red line is tilted -- can you explain how you're drawing it?

Comment: Dear Glen_b, in step 3 of the algorithm mentioned, I count the number of times the 95% CI for $$\phi$$ does NOT contain the original generated parameter. This will be roughly 5 times (5% of 100). I accumulate these counts in a vector of length 1000 ( since I am repeating this a 1000 times). In my code I call this count1_3_vector. Then I plot the obtained vs expected distribution via a qqplot. See line 89 in the code. Then I plot a red line in line 90 where I give the count1_3_vector and it's expected distribution.

Comment: So the part where I asked *how you draw the red line* is the part where your answer (the last line of your comment) is simply to refer me to the code?

Comment: Dear Glen_b,please see the edit to my original post.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're pointing me at. The answer to my question is that it's supposed to go through the quartiles of both the data and the expected distribution (via defaults in the call to qqline). However (and this is why I was asking) we can see that the observed and expected values lay very close to a 45 degree line -- which is what we should see. It's not clear to me why the red line is not on the 45 degree line, but whatever that issue is, the observed and expected quantiles seem relatively consistent.

Comment: Dear Glen_b, in the graph for \phi the red line does not agree which the quantiles in the tails. That's my query